# How to call create user function call in my custom Module Controller in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I am facing problem. I don't know what to do.. I want to call user create function in my custom module in magento.

> I want whole functionality of user create on my custom module
>   controller without pasting whole code.
>
> Is there a any way to hit create user function through my custom
>   controller.

I am using magento version 1.4.2

Thanks.

Comment: And what is the problem ? What have tou tried ? Maybe load customer model, set data and save ? Have you only tried anything ?

Comment: i want to hit create customer controller function unfortunately give fatal error.

Fatal error: Call to a member function createPostAction() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\myproject\app\code\local\test\Webservices\controllers\IndexController.php on line 342

Comment: "hit" what you mean by "hit" ? Explain more and show some code.

Comment: i have a function in my custom module controller and in function i want to call create user function.. and in the end function give response.

Comment: Were gonna need more code. Give us that whole function.